# Apollo Client - Cache Redirects for sub-types

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, vue-apollo

I am using Apollo in production for about a year and I am trying to optimize my cache management.
Let's imagine the following fictive simple schema:

```js
type Query {
  allBooks: [Book]
  allCups: [Cup]
  allColors: [Color]
}

type Book {
  id: Int
  name: String
  cover_color_id: Int
  CoverColor: Color
}

type Cup {
  id: Int
  name: String
  cover_color_id: Int
  CoverColor: Color
}

type Color {
  id: Int
  name: String
  hex_code: String
}
```

I would like to configure cacheRedirects so that when I demand the Book.CoverColor or Cup.CoverColor (via allBooks for instance ); it will first look for the Color with matching ID in the cache, before asking the server for it.
Is that possible ?

Thanks in advance!

PS: I tried this, which doesn't seem to work:

```js
cacheRedirects: {
  Query: {
    // Stuff that perfectly works
  },
  Book: {
    // this is not even executed :(
    CoverColor: (book, args, { getCacheKey }) => {
      return getCacheKey({
        __typename: 'Color',
        id: book.cover_color_id
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your queries look like.

if your `allBooks` redirect returns list of ids and your query has `returnPartialData` enabled it should work.

if you querying `allBooks` without hitting redirect, there is no reason for apollo to use cached fields on each element of `[Book]` if it already has all data

Make a query for a single book and it should work as you expect.

```
type Query {
  allBooks: [Book]
  allCups: [Cup]
  allColors: [Color]
  book(id: Int): Book
}
```

```js
const cacheRedirects: CacheResolverMap = {
  Query: {
    book: (_, args, { getCacheKey }) =>
      getCacheKey({ __typename: 'Book', id: `${args.id}` }),
  },
  Book: {
    CoverColor: (book, args, { getCacheKey }) => {
      return getCacheKey({
        __typename: 'Color',
        id: book.cover_color_id,
      })
    },
  },
}
```